# count rows from all tables and display before increment

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple tables with Nr_Crt as autoincrement in each table.
I am able to display the results from a query but my problem is this:
table 1

```
nr_crt |item
     1 |item 1
     2 |item 2
     3 |item 3
```

and table 2

```
nr_crt |item
     1 |song 1
     2 |song 2
     3 |song 3.
```

is there a way to display the result like this?

```
Nr. | Product
  1 |item 1
  2 |item 2
  3 |item 3
  4 |song 1
  5 |song 2
  6 |song 3
```

I know that i have to use something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM.....
Thank you.

Comment: If you don't care what's in songs `Nr.`, why not just create the incrementing numbers in PHP? It can be done in MySQL with user defined variables, but I don't see the point.

Comment: i don't want to join tables... i want to keep them separate

Comment: Union the tables instead.

Comment: LOL. Do a query that pulls data from both tables not actually join them

Comment: Wrikken how can i do incrementing numbers in PHP?

Comment: Never mind that... i have solved it with Wrikken's ideea.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS nr, 
       a.val            AS product 
FROM   (SELECT item AS val 
        FROM   table1 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT item 
        FROM   table2) a 
       JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

**Result**

```
| NR | PRODUCT |
----------------
|  1 |  item 1 |
|  2 |  item 2 |
|  3 |  item 3 |
|  4 |  song 1 |
|  5 |  song 2 |
|  6 |  song 3 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02c8c0/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  @rnk := @rnk + 1 nr_crt,
        a.item
FROM
        (
            SELECT  nr_crt, item, 1 ordr FROM TableA
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  nr_crt, item, 2 ordr FROM TableA
        ) a, (SELECT @rnk := 0) b
ORDER   BY a.ordr ASC, a.nr_crt ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0cee/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦════════╗
║ NR_CRT ║  ITEM  ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║      1 ║ item 1 ║
║      2 ║ item 2 ║
║      3 ║ item 3 ║
║      4 ║ item 1 ║
║      5 ║ item 2 ║
║      6 ║ item 3 ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```